# How do I stop Breaking Multiple Selectboxes with Javascript

Tags: jquery, forms, select, webforms, drop-down-menu

I created custom select dropdowns with jquery. When one select box is present it works great...but when TWO select boxes are present on the same page everything breaks down and only the last select element works correctly but it.

Code that works with one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var select = $('select.selectForm');

    var selectBoxContainer = $('<div>',{
       "class"     : 'selectContainer',
        html        : '<div class="selectBox"></div>'
    });

    var dropDown = $('<ul>',{
        "class"     : 'selectDropDown'
    });

    var selectBox = selectBoxContainer.find('.selectBox');


    //Loop though the options of the original select element
    select.find('option').each(function(i){
        var option = $(this);

        //sets default text to first option in the select
        if( i !== select.prop("selectedIndex") ){           
            selectBox.html( option.text() );
        }

        if( option.data('skip') ){
            return true;
        }

        //Creating a dropdown list from the items in out select element using the option text
        var li = $('<li>',{
            html : option.text()
        });

        li.on("click",function(){
            selectBox.html( option.text() );
            dropDown.trigger('hide'); //might be dropDown.trigger('hide');

            //also change the original select element
            select.val( option.val() );

            return false;
        });

        //add list item to the dropdown menu
        dropDown.append(li);

    });//end of select find

    //Adding dropdown to DOM
    selectBoxContainer.append(dropDown.hide()); //adding dropDown ul to DOM within the selectContainer div    
    select.hide().after(selectBoxContainer); //Hides original select element and inserts ul containder after it



    dropDown.bind('show',function(){
        if(dropDown.is(':animated')){
            return false;
        }
        selectBox.addClass('expanded');
        dropDown.slideDown();

    }).bind('hide',function(){

        if(dropDown.is(':animated')){
            return false;
        }

        selectBox.removeClass('expanded');
        dropDown.slideUp();

    }).bind('toggle',function(){

        if(selectBox.hasClass('expanded')){
            dropDown.trigger('hide');
        } else{
            dropDown.trigger('show');
        }
    });

    selectBox.on('click',function(){
        dropDown.trigger('toggle');
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click",function(){
        dropDown.trigger('hide');
    });


 });//document ready end
```

HOW IT WORKS WITH ONE:
http://jsfiddle.net/im_cr/TyPSX/

HOW IT BREAKS WITH TWO:
http://jsfiddle.net/im_cr/TyPSX/5/

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking for something more like this :

```
$.fn.selectForm = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var selectBox = $('<div />', {
                'class': 'selectBox'
            }),
            selectBoxContainer = $('<div />', {
                "class": 'selectContainer'
            }),
            dropDown = $('<ul />', {
                "class": 'selectDropDown'
            });

        selectBoxContainer.append(selectBox);

        $(this).find('option').each(function (i, option) {
            //sets default text to first option in the select
            if (i !== $(this).prop("selectedIndex")) {
                selectBox.html($(option).text());
            }

            if ($(option).data('skip')) {
                return true;
            }

            //Creating a dropdown list from the items in out select element using the option text
            var li = $('<li>', {
                html: $(option).text(),
                on: {
                    click: function () {
                        selectBox.html($(option).text());
                        dropDown.trigger('hide'); //might be dropDown.trigger('hide');
                        select.val(option.value);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            dropDown.append(li);
        }); //end of select find

        selectBoxContainer.append(dropDown.hide());
        $(this).hide().after(selectBoxContainer);

        dropDown.bind('show', function () {
            if (dropDown.is(':animated')) {
                return false;
            }
            selectBox.addClass('expanded');
            dropDown.slideDown();
        }).bind('hide', function () {
            if (dropDown.is(':animated')) {
                return false;
            }
            selectBox.removeClass('expanded');
            dropDown.slideUp();
        }).bind('toggle', function () {
            if (selectBox.hasClass('expanded')) {
                dropDown.trigger('hide');
            } else {
                dropDown.trigger('show');
            }
        });

        selectBox.on('click', function () {
            dropDown.trigger('toggle');
            return false;
        });

        $(document).on("click", function () {
            dropDown.trigger('hide');
        });
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('select.selectForm').selectForm();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TyPSX/7/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch @adeneo , i really appreciate it. Did it work correctly because the data was returned to the plugin or in part because you separated out the creation of the some the ul elements?...Thanks again!

Comment: I just created a plugin for convenience, and by doing so it solved the issue, which was creating a new instance and new elements for each select element, hence the loop.